Create an xarray DataArray from a 3 dimensional array in Python
I have a 3 dimensional array like this:
[[lon,lon,lon],
 [lat,lat,lat],
 [value,value,value]]

I have been trying to create an xarray DataArray from it but somehow I can't wrap my head around it. I can create a one dimensional DataArray with
lon = an[0]
val = an[2]
da = xr.DataArray(val, coords={"lon":lon})

I have also tried with an array in the format
[[lon,lat,value],
 [lon,lat,value],
 [lon,lat,value]]

without success. How can I create a DataArray with lat and lon dimensions from my source array?
